# Seal out draft from sliding, frameless shower door

Tags: shower, weatherstripping

There is a draft coming from the vertical gap between the two sliding doors on my shower.

Is there some sort of sweep or stripping designed for this purpose?  Lacking that, are there any alternatives I can use to keep the cold air out?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go for winter weather stripping, but I don't see that lasting too long. So, I'd really say go with car door Edge Moldings. There are a variety of widths & colors, they just slip over the edge & can be glued if the friction fit doesn't hold-up, literally. You'll probably want to do both doors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Iggy. I will look around for something that suits my door before I mark accepted.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I don't have another good option in mind, but these should work out great. If you've seen a cheap mirror with a plastic type gold band edging, that's basically what they are but the car ones are better quality.